# Sunburst diagram in with sunburstR package in R

Tags: r, sunburst-diagram

I am using the [sunburstR package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sunburstR/sunburstR.pdf) to create a sunburst diagram but it is not working and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Raw data:

```
  > sequences
                 V1
    1  A-aa-aaa-end
    2  A-aa-aaa-end
    3  A-aa-vvv-end
    4  A-aa-vvv-end
    5  A-cc-vvv-end
    6  A-cc-vvv-end
    7  B-aa-vvv-end
    8  B-aa-vvv-end
    9   B-bb-rr-end
    10  B-bb-rr-end
    11  C-aa-rr-end
    12  C-aa-rr-end
    13  C-bb-rr-end
    14  C-bb-rr-end
    15  C-cc-rr-end
```

Code:

```
sequences <- read.csv(filepath, header=F ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sunburst(sequences)
```

Comment: two columns are needed. one with the sequence, another with the values.

Answer (score 1):

You need some values in the second column of your data frame...

```
sequences <- read.table(text = '
A-aa-aaa-end
A-aa-aaa-end
A-aa-vvv-end
A-aa-vvv-end
A-cc-vvv-end
A-cc-vvv-end
B-aa-vvv-end
B-aa-vvv-end
B-bb-rr-end
B-bb-rr-end
C-aa-rr-end
C-aa-rr-end
C-bb-rr-end
C-bb-rr-end
C-cc-rr-end
')

sequences$V2 <- seq_along(sequences$V1)
sequences

library(sunburstR)
sunburst(sequences)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the count part. Try `sunburst(data.frame(table(sequences$V1)))` and it should work as expected.

PS : not tested without the `sequences` dataframe.